# Check if "Send the new user an email about their account" is ticked

Tags: email, user-registration, notifications

I am trying to over-ride the wp_new_user_notification() function but I am having issues checking if the user has been approved or if "Send the new user an email about their account" is checked.

The reason I need to perform these checks is because I have noticed that the over-ride ignores if a user is approved or not and also ignores if "Send the new user an email about their account" checkbox is ticked or not.

```
if ( !function_exists('wp_new_user_notification') ) {
    function wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, $plaintext_pass = '' ) {

        $user = new WP_User($user_id);
        $plaintext_pass = wp_generate_password();
        wp_set_password( $plaintext_pass, $user_id );

        $user_login = stripslashes($user->user_login);
        $user_email = stripslashes($user->user_email);

        if ( empty($plaintext_pass) )
        return;


        if(get_user_meta($current_user->ID,'active',true) == 1){
          $subject = "Thank you for registering for ".get_option('blogname')."";
          $message = "Thank you for registering for ".get_option('blogname')."\n";
          $message .= "Your registration for ".get_option('blogname')." has been approved.\n\n";
          $message .= "Your registration information is below.\n";
          $message .= "You may wish to retain a copy for your records.\n\n";
          $message .= "username: ".$user_login."\n";
          $message .= "password:  ".$plaintext_pass."\n\n";
          $message .= "You may log in here:\n";
          $message .= site_url( '/')."\n\n";
          $message .= "----------------------------------\n";
          $message .= "This is an automated message from ".get_option('blogname')."\n";
          $message .= "Please do not reply to this address\n";

          wp_mail($user_email, sprintf(__('[%s] Your username and password'), get_option('blogname')), $message);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: have you looked at the source of the original function?

Comment: Yes but I couldn't find anything that checks if the "Send the new user an email about their account." is checked or not.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found a solution. Not sure if it is the best solution but at least it serves the purpose:

```
if ( !function_exists('wp_new_user_notification') ) {
  function wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, $plaintext_pass = '' ) {

    if($_POST['action'] == 'createuser'){

      if($_POST['send_user_notification'] == 1){

        $user = new WP_User($user_id);
        $plaintext_pass = $_POST['pass1'];
        wp_set_password( $plaintext_pass, $user_id );

        $user_login = stripslashes($user->user_login);
        $user_email = stripslashes($user->user_email);

        if ( empty($plaintext_pass) )
        return;

        if($_POST['activate_user'] == 1){
          $headers = "From: xxxxxx <xxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.xx>\r\n";
          $subject = "Thank you for registering for ".get_option('blogname')."";
          $message = "Thank you for registering here are your log in details keep them safe, your account is now active\n\n";
          $message .= "username: ".$user_login."\n";
          $message .= "password:  ".$plaintext_pass."\n\n";
          $message .= "Click here to log in:\n";
          $message .= site_url( '/')."\n\n";
          $message .= "----------------------------------\n";
          $message .= "This is an automated message from ".get_option('blogname')."\n";
          $message .= "Please do not reply to this address\n";

          wp_mail($user_email, $subject, $message, $headers);

        }else{

          $headers = "From: xxxxxx <xxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.xx>\r\n";
          $subject = "Thank you for registering for ".get_option('blogname')."";
          $message = "Thank you for registering here are your log in details keep them safe, your account is pending so we will be in touch shortly\n\n";
          $message .= "username: ".$user_login."\n";
          $message .= "password:  ".$plaintext_pass."\n\n";
          $message .= "----------------------------------\n";
          $message .= "This is an automated message from ".get_option('blogname')."\n";
          $message .= "Please do not reply to this address\n";

          wp_mail($user_email, $subject, $message, $headers);

        }

      }

    }
  }
}
```